# Mongo last comment collection of users

Tags: mongodb, collections

Lets say I have a collection of users

`_id: ...
name: 'the name'`

and a collection of comments

`_id: ...
comment: 'the comment'
poster: user_id`

And then use a single query to get the last comments from a list of users?

Comment: Could you post the sample collections

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make it in single query is to run aggregation pipeline with $lookup stage
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/